# Accessing files with different permission and no sudo access

Tags: linux

Under my user home directory I have a file called `passwords.txt` which is owned by a another user. I don't have `sudo` access.

Permission of the passwords.txt file is `r-x------ spual spaul`

How can I read this text file?

Answer (score 6):

You ask the system administrator or the user `spaul` to give you permission.

Comment: I'd ask the system administrator or `spaul` just what in the devil `spaul`'s passwords.txt file is doing in someone else's home directory.

Comment: You might have better luck asking the owner of the home directory, who in many setups will generally be the only (unprivileged) person with write permission.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP it seems that the OP is the owner of the home directory, but the file in it is not accessible to them.

Comment: I did ask the sys admin but he told me there is a way to solve it. "An easy puzzle to solve". @JdeBP- the file is on my home directory.

Comment: Write permission _on the directory_ roaima.

Comment: @JdeDP how does that allow the OP to read the file as asked?

Comment: Read what is directly preceding what I wrote.

Comment: @JdeBP I have read the comments. And reread them. You seem to be answering a question here in comments that hasn't been asked. If not please clarify what you're hinting at because I'm missing your point.

Comment: I think that I understand the confusion.  Read what Nasir Riley said, then read what I wrote as if it were a response to it placed directly below it, which in fact it is.  (-:  Then mull over the three ways in which a file owned by `spaul` gets into a `spectrum:spectrum` directory that has permissions 0755 or 0750, as is commonly the case nowadays.

Comment: @JdeBP ah ok. I wasn't even considering _how_ the file had arrived there. Relaxed `$HOME` permissions (group/other) or root access would be one route. More sophisticated could be something like a setuid-`spaul` program that this OP had run. The question asked is "How can I read this file", which is what I was addressing in my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470890/100397).

Answer (score 0):

If the hard drive or the home folder is not encrypted you have two options:

1. Access the file via a live system (if you are allowed to boot).
2. Plug the hard drive to another computer you have root/sudo rights and access the file.

If not, refer to @roaima's answer.

Answer (score -3):

This worked:

```
sudo –u spaul /bin/cat passwords.txt
```

Comment: If this worked, your question gives wrong details, namely "I don't have `sudo` access."

Comment: still i dont have sudo access on the machine, create a similar environment and try it.

Comment: You're not making sense I'm afraid. You say you don't have `sudo` access but your working solution uses `sudo`. Huh?